# Gradle startScript - Could not find or load main class

Tags: gradle

After looking into various answers in SO regarding the topic (which did not help me), I am raising a new question

I am new to Gradle, using version 1.0
Working with `application` plugin

it looks pretty simple
but I am facing difficulty running the start script

**when I run the start script for windows, it says "Error: Cannot load or find main class"**

Whereas with `gradle run` it runs successfully

here is my gradle file:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

def properties = new Properties()
file('build.properties').withReader { properties.load(it) }
properties.each { key, value -> project.ext.set(key, value) }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.0'
}

mainClassName = 'org.sample.Main'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'

repositories {
    ....
}

jar {
    manifest {
        def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { 
it.getName() }\
.join(' ')
        attributes(
            'Manifest-Version'      : 1.0,
            'Specification-Title'   : project.ext.specTitle,
            'Sepcification-Version' : project.ext.specVersion,
            'Specification-Vendor'  : project.ext.specVendor,
            'Implementation-Title'  : project.ext.implTitle,
            'Implementation-Version': project.ext.implVersion,
            'Implementation-Vendor' : project.ext.specVendor,
            'Main-Class' : 'org.sample.Main',
            'Class-Path'            : manifestClasspath
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason to use Gradle 1?  current version is 5.2, API has changed a lot.

Comment: It's a project requirement but not so strict, 
I tried same thing with 5.2 , still facing same issue